# Divide two numeric columns in SQL and create new column with varchar result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to divide two columns in SQL, I want to then have the results in a new column with a truncated result and by adding a decimal point. I'm at a loss here trying to get the syntax right.

Basically, column X and Y are numeric and I want the resulting value to be a percentage.

```
     X/NULLIF (Y,0) * 100 AS PERCENTAGE
```

My result ends up as

```
X.XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Ideally, I'm trying to get a result of

```
 X.XX%
```

But my syntax of

```
X/NULLIF(Y,0) * 100 + '$' AS PERCENTAGE
```

won't work since I can't convert type varchar to numeric. Also as to how to get a truncated result.

I tried casting, but that did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str()` or `cast()` to a decimal.  For your purposes, you want a string, so `str()` is more appropriate:

```
SELECT str(X/NULLIF(Y, 0) * 100, 5, 2) + '%'
```

Note that this does left align the results, so you might consider:

```
SELECT cast(cast(100 * X/NULLIF(Y, 0) as decimal(5, 2)) as varchar(255)) + '%'
```

Comment: That worked! So to understand, you are casting the arithmetic and then the entire value as a whole?

Comment: @eldiablo1121 . . . `round()` affects the *value* but not the type.  `cast()` (and `str()`) affect the type of the result, which in turn determines the structure of the output.